# remove second decimal if it exists

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare versions of Mac OS, however in some browsers

`10.11` is returned in others `10.11.3` is returned. How can I remove that last decimal so it's always `10.11`, but only remove it if it exists. (to avoid removing the first one).

Thanks.

Comment: Check if there's more than one period, if so, remove everything after the second period.

Comment: Hard to believe this is a question from someone with 2k rep.

Comment: What should happen in the case of, as an example, Mac OS 10.11.2 and Mac OS 10.11.3; if you remove the `.2` and `.3` should they evaluate to the same version, even though that's not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var versionstring1 = "10.2.1",
    versionstring2 = "10.1";

function getVersion(versionstring, asString, maxdepth) {
  maxdepth = maxdepth || 2;
  var truncatedVersion = versionstring.split('.').slice(0, maxdepth);
  return !!asString ? truncatedVersion.join('.') : truncatedVersion;
}

console.log(getVersion(versionstring1));
console.log(getVersion(versionstring2));
// or as string:
console.log(getVersion(versionstring1, true));
console.log(getVersion(versionstring2, true));
```